# php soap indexed array in request

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I want to pass multiple indexed array to my SOAP service

```
$params = array(
    'Stuffs' => array(
        'stuffsArray' => array(
            array('itemid' => 100, 'qty' => 2),
            array('itemid' => 101, 'qty' => 1),
            array('itemid' => 102, 'qty' => 3)
        )
    )
);
```

My script for nuSOAP looks like

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Stuffs',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'itemid' => array(
            'name' => 'itemid',
            'type' => 'xsd:int'
        ),
        'qty' => array(
            'name' => 'qty',
            'type' => 'xsd:int'
        )
    )
); 
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'StuffsArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array(
            'ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
            'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Stuffs[]'
        )
    ),
    'tns:Stuffs'
);
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'req',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'Stuffs' => array('name' => 'Stuffs', 'type' => 'tns:StuffsArray')
    )
);
```

whith generated WSDL I can pass only one element in array stuffsArray to get response

```
$params = array(
    'Stuffs' => array(
        'stuffsArray' => array(
            'itemid' => 100, 'qty' => 2
        )
    )
);
```

But I need to pass multiple data in stuffsArray, many values for itemid and qty.
How I can write addComplexType to approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial helps me to solve my question

http://www.koopman.me/2006/09/repeating-same-name-parameters-with-nusoap/